# mongo gem error when chef-client run

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

My attributes.rb file contains **require 'mongo'**, while chef-client runs, after synchronize cookbooks it goes to compile every cookbooks and after that got an error of **'require mongo'** not found. I have describe to install gem in other cookbooks. so what i want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You shouldn't require gems in attributes.
2. If you want to install mongo gem you should use [`chef_gem`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_chef_gem.html) or [`gem_package`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_gem_package.html) resource in you **recipies**. You can also use [`gem` method in metadata.rb](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_metadata.html), it will work like `chef_gem` resource.

Comment: Hi @Szymon, Thanks for your quick reply, but I use mongo gem to load data from mongo db server, so for that i need mongo gem and also have recipe to install mongo gem, but while compiling cookbooks on chef-client run, i face error because no mongo gem is installed at that time....

Comment: Your recipe probably doesn't install gem on run-time, chef works in two phases, [here](https://coderanger.net/two-pass/) you can read more about it. It would help if you would show us your recipe and full error log.

Comment: I face issues on compiling stage, here is my attributes.rb file                   `require 'mongo'
client = Mongo::Client.new('mongodb://172.31.19.21:27017/abcdef')`

Comment: Unfortunately the mongo gem depends on the bson gem, and that has a C extension, so you'll need to entirely rework your code. You can't install C gems super early because you need to wait until a C compiler toolchain is installed.